# Excel's COUNTA equivalent in Access VBA to return number of non-empty rows from a spreadsheet

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I want to run some VBA in Access to get a count of the number of rows that contain data within a specified range of cells in an Excel document.

In Excel `COUNTA` does this nicely, but how would I achieve the same result from Access VBA? It would only need to look at 1 column of data.

Example locations to reference:

**Full Path**:

- C:\Users\Matt\Desktop\ExcelFile.xls

**Sheet in Excel with the rows I need to count**:

- ExcelSheet

**Starting cell reference**

i.e. the top and leftmost cell; so if I were using `COUNTA` in Excel, I'd look at a range such as `COUNTA(A14:A5000)`:

- A14

**Edit:** code I've tried, but I'm getting an error:

```vb
Option Compare Database

Sub ImportDataFromRange()

Dim xlFilePath As String
Dim rowVariable As String

xlFilePath = "C:\Users\Matt\Desktop\MattExcelFile.xls"

rowVariable = Excel.Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Workbooks(xlFilePath).Sheets("ExcelSheet").Range("A14:A5000"))

Debug.Print rowVariable

End Sub

Private Sub Command0_Click()

ImportDataFromRange

End Sub
```

Error message I receive when running this code, highlighting the `rowVariable = ...` line:

> Run-time error '9':
>
> Subscript out of range

Comment: Is the workbook currently open? Otherwise you won't be able to reference it via the `Workbooks` collection.

Answer (score 1):

You can use worksheet functions from within VBA; see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh211481%28v=office.14%29.aspx). Just add a reference to the Excel object model.